# How to limit which fields can be updated in a form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am making a form in MS Access 2013 and it has 5 fields, this form is used to create an "Event." When creating an event, all 5 fields are used. However, the same form is also used to update an event. When updating an event, only three of the fields should be changed. How can I make it so that two of the fields are ignored when updating? I do not want to make a separate form for updating.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set field.enabled = false if the primary key of a record (shoudl be a field of type autovalue) is set to a value in the Form_Current trogger, i.e. do something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If IsNull(Me!pk) Then
        Me!Field.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me!Field.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

(just replace pk and Field with your real field names)